# In eclipse, can we change font style of a section of code, unlike the global?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, code-formatting

We already know that we can change the font styles for Eclipse editors globally. But let's say I want to change font for particular block of code or line of code by selecting the text just like a word processing software.

Life would be easier if we went through big classes and color-coded the block of code with different styles.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there any way we can change the font of a section of a code in Eclipse. But, we can use plugins like **EditBox** to highlight sections of code in Eclipse. EditBox is also configurable so you can create your own color presets.

Hope this helps :)

Try: http://editbox.sourceforge.net/